# Alternate Publish Actions for Submitting a Facebook HighScore?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, unity-game-engine

I'd like to submit a simple highscore onto the Facebook Open Graph and I'm doing it through Unity/Facebook SDK for Android. I'm using the built in:

```
FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST etc**.....
```

Everything is working.

However, I'm really unhappy that I need to request `publish_actions` permissions, in order to submit a score. (I'm requesting these permissions on login).

Reason:

1. It pops out 2 dialogues. One for accessing public profile, & then a "Post to your friends on your behalf.
2. I tested my app on my sister, and witnessed her instinctively declining the 2nd Dialogue :"Post to your friends on your behalf"..

So basically, majority of people will not be submitting highscores, simply because they decline the misleading "Post to your friends on your behalf" request. when I simply want to submit a number >.<

Which defeats the purpose of my whole app, which is friends/social highscore based.

Does anyone know any alternative strategies to submit highscores onto Facebook Open Graph in a more "friendlier" manner?

Would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything regarding this- this is **by design**.

Try to understand- if facebook dont show this dialog, then apps can publish spam etc. on the user's wall unnecessarily. So, in order to save the spamming etc. this dialog appears so that user can "choose", whether he wants to allow the app to publish on his behalf or not. This is necessary, hope it makes sense for you!

Comment: Thanks Sahil. I understand a prompt to prevent spam, and i believe  that because of FB stories, that it needs this permission. I now have to create a "Player needs to agree to terms and conditions" (allow Posting on Behalf) in order to Login... However, i believe that uploading a simple Integer and posting stories should be 2 seperate things, and that it shouldnt be bundled together.. By current design... it is as it is.... but through my user feedback, i can only hope it can be iterated to become nicer in the future..